Is it possible to set the current index in `progressr`?
In some processes, intermediate results force recalculation of earlier ones.  Can the progressr package support changes to the progression index during the calculation, so
I could report
step 1
step 2
step 3 oops, need to go back
step 2
step 3
step 4
done

Here's some code that doesn't work:
f <- function() {
  p <- progressr::progressor(4)
  i <- 0
  while (i < 4) {
    i <- i + 1
    p(message = sprintf("at step %d", i))
    if (i == 3 && runif(1) < 0.5) {
      p(message = "Oops, need to go back")
      i <- 2
    }
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
}
handlers(global = TRUE)

set.seed(123)
f()

It steps through from 1 to 4, then gives nothing, and a lot of warnings at the end.

the progress package (which is for cli) definitely supports negative ticks etc; it seems that progressr currently does not.

@NirGraham:  Thanks, that's helpful.  Do you want to post it as an answer?

the progress package (which is for cli) definitely supports negative ticks etc; it seems that progressr currently does not.

I followed @NirGraham's advice, and modified my code example like this:
f <- function() {
  p <- progress::progress_bar$new(show_after = 0)
  i <- 0
  while (i < 4) {
    i <- i + 1
    p$update(i/4)
    if (i == 3 && runif(1) < 0.9)
      i <- 1
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
}

set.seed(1)
f()

Rather than using a negative tick amount, I used the update method which sets a fraction of completion directly.
It would be nice if progressr allowed this kind of thing.  I like its design better than that of progress:  it is much easier for a user to turn off the progress bar.
